# Avoiding class constraint on type level naturals

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I am using the `Nat` type in from the [`GHC.TypeLits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html) module, which admittedly says the programmer interface should be defined in a separate library. In any case, the [`GHC.TypeLits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html) has a class [`KnownNat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:KnownNat) with a class function [`natVal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:natVal) which converts a compile time `Nat` into a runtime `Integer`. There's also a type function [`(+)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:-43-) which adds compile time `Nat`s.

The problem is that given `(KnownNat n1, KnownNat n2)`, GHC can't derive that `KnownNat (n1 + n2)`.

This results in an explosion of constraints needed to be added whenever I add type level naturals.

One alternative would be to define Natural numbers myself like so:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

Or perhaps use a library like [type-natural](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-natural-0.7.1.2/docs/Data-Type-Natural.html). But it seems silly to not use the Nats which are built into GHC, which also allow you to nicely use literal numbers in types (i.e. `0`, `1`) instead of having to define:

```
N0 = Zero
N1 = Succ N0
etc...
```

Is there anyway around this issue with GHC [`KnownNat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:KnownNat) constraints being required all over the place? Or should I just ignore the [`GHC.TypeLits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html) module for my problem?

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492754/could-not-deduce-knownnat-in-two-existentials-with-respect-to-the-singletons-lib/41496362) and the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This GHC type checker plugin does exactly that (derives "complex" `KnownNat` constraints from other ones already available): https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-knownnat

If "type checker plugin" sounds a little intimidating (it did to me at first), it's actually very simple to use. Simply add it as a dependency in your package file (or cabal install it) like any other package, then either add:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Normalise #-}
```

to the start of your source files (much like a `LANGUAGE` pragma), or add it as an option globally in your package file.

There's also another plugin by the same author that's very useful as well for working with typelit Nats: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-natnormalise. This one is able to infer equality of Nat type expressions that GHC on its own gives up on: things like `n + (m + 1) ~ (n + 1) + m` that come up all the time when GHC is trying to prove "expected" and "actual" types match.